# Spring MVC: Bind checkbox to int value

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Domain:

```
public class Record {   
    ...
    private int STATE;
    ...
// getters and setters
}
```

controller:

```
...
@RequestMapping("recordInsert")
public String insertRecord(@ModelAttribute Record record) {     
    if (record != null){            
        recordService.insertRecord(record);}
    return "redirect:/recordGetList";
}
```

JSP page:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/recordInsert" modelAttribute="record">
...
<tr>
    <td>Enabled :</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" path="STATE"  /></td>
</tr>
...
```

Problem is to bind checkbox to int value. I need set 1 when checkbox is checked and 0 when not checked. I need to use PropertyEditor in my controller

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{       
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, ...);
}
```

but I don't understand how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
<form:checkbox path="STATE"/>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work you can create a fake property using set/getter taking a boolean and you can set inside the value of your integer